# JavaScript: Method That's Never Loses Binding

Tags: javascript, this, custom-element

Consider this basic custom element:

```
class XElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super(); }
  foo() { console.log( this ); }
} customElements.define( 'x-element', XElement );
```

Here is the problem:

```
const xelem = new XElement();

/* `foo` will lose its binding to `xelem`:
*/ someButton.onclick = xelem.foo;

// These will work, but it's too verbose:
someButton.onclick = () => xelem.foo();
someButton.onclick = xelem.foo.bind( xelem );
```

---

I see only one solution is to add `foo` as arrow function in constructor, but it seems to me wrong.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.foo = () => console.log( this );
}
```

Is there any right way to create method that will never lose its binding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is how JavaScript `this` binding works.

You can read this: [THIS (YDKJS)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)
Basically, the value of `this` inside a function depends upon how that function is invoked. So you need to explicitly hard bind the `this` value to your function `foo` by using the bind() method or defining `foo` as arrow function (arrow functions lexically bind their context).

So the solution is what you found.

You can do:

In your constructor:

```
class XElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { 
   super(); 
   this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);   
  }
  foo() { console.log( this ); }
}
```

Or (I don't like this one)

```
class XElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { 
   super(); 
   this.foo = () => console.log(this);   
  }
}
```

Or

```
class XElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super(); }
  foo = () => { console.log( this ); }
}
```

Comment: I never thought I can do `foo = 'whatever'` right inside class body.